# BIOS not seeing Ubuntu installed on Acer Aspire ES1-132. Can boot via grub cli

Tags: grub2, partitioning, acer, boot-partition, aspire

(Lots of info in the title so that other people with the same problem may find it.)

I bought an Acer Aspire ES1-132, knowing that installing Linux might be a bit of a hassle.

What I have done so far:

- Updated BIOS (InsydeH20) to version 1.09.
- Disabled "Secure Boot" in BIOS.
- Ran the Ubuntu Live-USB and installed on the HDD (eMMC).
- Did not use guided partitioning and created 3 partitions according to
  this guide: [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)
- Got "No bootable device" on startup.

This is where I am:
If I start the computer with the live-usb I can access the grub cli (c key at the usb boot loader menu) and by running these commands I can mount access the installed Ubuntu desktop, seemingly without other problems:

```
set root=(hd1,2)
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/mmcblk0p2
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

And if I just put the computer in sleep mode it "starts" as usual. The annoying thing is having to carry a usb-drive around every time I need to restart the thing.

If I run **lsblk** I get:

```
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0rpmb    179:24   0    4M  0 disk  
mmcblk0boot0   179:8    0    4M  1 disk  
mmcblk0boot1   179:16   0    4M  1 disk  
mmcblk0        179:0    0 58,2G  0 disk  
├─mmcblk0p2    179:2    0 18,6G  0 part  /
├─mmcblk0p3    179:3    0 35,8G  0 part  /home
└─mmcblk0p1    179:1    0  3,8G  0 part  
  └─cryptswap1 253:0    0  3,8G  0 crypt [SWAP]
```

and **df**:

```
Filesystem          1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                  1913736       0   1913736   0% /dev
tmpfs                  387044    6472    380572   2% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p2       19091584 5867364  12231352  33% /
tmpfs                 1935208   63800   1871408   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                 1935208       0   1935208   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p3       36819652  872108  34054168   3% /home
tmpfs                  387044      12    387032   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs                  387044      92    386952   1% /run/user/1000
/home/jens/.Private  36819652  872108  34054168   3% /home/jens
```

So when I restart the computer I get a "No bootable device".

What I have tried that didn't work:

- Set "trusted file" (or whatever it's called) in the BIOS, since that option isn't available to me, even after setting supervisor password.
- Running boot-repair, when I do I can no longer use the method I have now to access the OS.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Because you mention "secure boot" we know you have UEFI, not BIOS. Installing in UEFI mode always requires a ESP (EFI System Partition), a small (>500MB) FAT partition where the boot entries (files) for this method are stored. More details at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI . The partitioning scheme you used applies to old BIOS only.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment!

 Could I use the instructions for "Converting Ubuntu to UEFI mode" on this page? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Creating_an_EFI_System_Partition

Comment: Don' t know, never did it, but looks promising.

Comment: I'll give it a go. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. :)

Comment: Okay, tried it without luck. I created a /boot/efi partition, edited fstab and set boot flag with gparted, but nothing.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: I could definitely do that @RodSmith, but I seem to have fixed my issue (se answer below). Would you still like me to upload to help other users in the future?

Comment: No, the details in your Boot Repair report would be applicable to your computer alone, or at best only to computers that are identical in whatever key area was causing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Many thanks fpl2 - you gave me vital info that I've been after having had a few runs at this.

Note all of this was done with Secure Boot disabled and starting with USB boot at top of list as bootable devices.

I managed to do a clean minimal install of Ubuntu 18.04 with a live USB stick on my Acer Aspire ES1-132-C8WF. This time, though, without requiring REFIND, I found that after my install if I run the Ubuntu installation USB again, then run a live session (Try Ubuntu) and do the following in a terminal (you obviously could do this in 3 or 4 commands, but this lets you see the manual steps as you go):

```
sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt
cd /mnt
ls
cd EFI
ls
sudo mkdir Microsoft
cd Microsoft
sudo mkdir Boot
cd Boot
sudo cp -r /mnt/EFI/ubuntu/* .
sudo mv shimx64.efi bootmgfw.efi
```

and hey presto! it boots, and the 'Windows Boot Manager' magically puts 'Windows Boot' (which is now actually Ubuntu 18.04) to the top of the list in the F2 boot menu.

Comment: That's awesome man! I'm glad it worked for you. I have given up long ago and the thing is just collecting dust... might be time to give it another try.

Comment: Thanks Jens. I've actually being using same laptop with older version of Ubuntu on it for over a year now with a USB 'boot dongle' with REFIND on it. I now figure I could have actually used above instructions at any time without the need to re-install anything, and with no loss of data, but getting rid of the dongle. Be nice to know if anyone dares to confirm this.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I installed LinuxMint in this laptop, and this is the link helped me to install...

I have found a way to boot Ubuntu on a russian linux forum, where the reason for this problem is explained. The reason for it is that someone naughty has hardcoded all possible paths you can use to boot your system ('thanks a lot'). The paths are:

```
\EFI\Linux\BOOTX64.efi (Linux)
\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi (Windows Boot Manager)
\EFI\ubuntu\shim.efi (ubuntu SECURE)
\EFI\ubuntu\shim$cpu$.efi (ubuntu SECURE)
\EFI\ubuntu\grub.efi (ubuntu NORMAL)
\EFI\fedora\shim.efi (Fedora)
\EFI\android\bootx64.efi (Android)
\EFI\opensuse\grubx64.efi (topenSUSE)
\EFI\redhat\grub.efi (Red Hat Linux)
\EFI\SuSE\elilo.efi (SuSE Linux)
\EFI\ubuntu\grub$cpu$.efi (ubuntu NORMAL)
```

Referring to [this post on community.acer.com](http://community.acer.com/t5/E-F-V-and-M-Series-Laptops/ES1-132-cannot-install-other-OS-than-Windows-10-BIOS-options/td-p/476726/page/2)

Comment: I just saw this answer now. Do you have a link to all the steps you took to install LinuxMint? I still have not gotten a hang of this (just let the thing hang out in my bookshelf for a while).

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I have no hair left, but a solution. If you are in the same state that I was this might work.

Here is what I did.

- Enter BIOS. Set an admin password and then disable secure boot.
- Install Ubuntu and use manual partitioning. Follow this post: [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) but also add a third partition that is 200mb, mount point `/boot/efi`, type fat32 and a boot flag.
- Create the `/boot/efi/EFI/boot` directory.
- Download rEFInd [from here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html) and install it. Then move and rename the `/boot/efi/refind/refind_x64.efi` file to `/boot/efi/EFI/boot/grubx64.efi`.

After that it COULD work. As I said, I've been back and forth with this and I might've missed something. If anyone else has something that I missed or any part of this ^ that looks stupid then please enlighten me, because I'm fairly lost.

Edit: If you do do this and then have the double login screen issue, try to fix it any other way than by removing `gnome-screensaver`. That just put me back at square one.

Luckily I was able to fix it by moving the refind boot-loader to /boot/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi.

Comment: If you do this: don't try to fix multiple login screen issue by removing gnome-screensaver... back to square 1.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu:
solution by fpl2 on ubuntuforums

The "refind" solution works on my ES1-132 crap.
BIOS 1.15., hdd replaced with ssd, Supervisor password set ( not sure if any of this matters but you`ll need Windows to update your BIOS so do it if you can - thank Acer for this too)

It goes like this:

- enable secure boot
- install ubuntu - if secure boot is not enabled the installation won`t create EFI partition
- after install the ubuntu won`t boot
- disable secure boot - (not sure if this is needed but I`ve done so many things that this is how it was left on my successful run )
- boot from the flash drive using "try ubuntu..."
- mount the efi partition somewhere  - in my case /mnt/efissd
- download and extract the "refind" package somewhere else
- go to /mnt/efissd/EFI/
- create Microsoft/Boot dir - endresult should be /mnt/efissd/EFI/Microsoft/Boot
- copy refind_x64.efi from "refind" package to EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
- reboot

Thanks to all the good people who found this solution in this and other threads

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this when I have the computer. I can't update to BIOS 1.15 though, since I don't have Windows anymore.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot from Ubuntu live USB and select the *Try Ubuntu without installing* option.
2. Launch GParted to get the EFI partition address. In my case this is `/dev/mmcblk0p1`.
3. Open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
4. Create a media directory and attach it to the EFI partition directory:

   ```bash
   sudo mkdir /media/EFI   
   sudo mount <enter your path here>/media/EFI
   ```

   In my case it looked like this:

   ```bash
   sudo mkdir /media/EFI   
   sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1/media/EFI
   ```
5. Create the `/EFI/Linux/` directory:

   ```bash
   sudo mkdir /media/EFI/EFI/Linux
   ```
6. Copy all existing files from the directory you created when installing Ubuntu. In my case the default directory is `/EFI/ubuntu/`:

   ```
   $ sudo ls /media/EFI/EFI/ubuntu   
   BOOTX64.CSV   
   fw   
   fwupx64.efi   
   grub.cfg   
   grubx64.efi   
   mmx64.efi   
   shimx64.efi
   ```

   To do this run the following command:

   ```bash
   sudo cp -R /media/EFI/EFI/ubuntu/* /media/EFI/EFI/Linux/
   ```
7. Copy the `BOOTX64.EFI` file from the `BOOT` directory to the `Linux` directory (without confirmation that it did not work for 2 weeks):

   ```bash
   sudo cp /media/EFI/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI /media/EFI/EFI/Linux
   ```
8. Close all windows and reboot with `sudo reboot`.

Comment: All Acer requires "trust" setting in UEFI to boot anything other than Windows. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot
 and Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947