# Boot problem Acer aspire

Tags: boot, acer

I am trying to install 16.4 on an Acer aspire e11 but it will not boot after install. It runs OK from the live usb drive any suggestions please.

Comment: What is written on screen after booting?

Comment: If you installed in UEFI mode (which you should have), then you need to set "trust" from inside UEFI. https://askubuntu.com/questions/771455/dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-on-acer-aspire/771749#771749

Answer (score 1):

On my Acer Aspire there vas a line missing in the fstab file (/etc/fstab), the EFI system partition!
run:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="30AB-667B" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="623e7385-ee5d-49b8-bc18-dbde551f5067"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Acer" UUID="8A1EAD321EAD1869" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="8ae7090d-3565-438e-9146-073ec0670de3"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="2CD2AF55D2AF2256" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="e337e795-6016-4fdc-a552-3d3cf469b6c9"
/dev/sda5: UUID="b81dd225-11b1-4783-81ff-1572f8058c23" TYPE="swap" PARTLABEL="Swap area" PARTUUID="71233eb1-916f-4bc1-bcfa-dd62f662c81a"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="MintXfce" UUID="05130fba-7126-4d1c-8bfa-bde9f2a79ea9" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Linux Mint" PARTUUID="e38142cd-8120-4764-bd17-8a8fae6a2aa3"
/dev/sda7: LABEL="Voyager" UUID="3068f167-88f1-44bb-8b5d-628681dd9536" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Vouager" PARTUUID="73b60fe3-bc04-40a4-aeee-ff4cdb3cf5db"
/dev/sda8: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="53942c96-b474-4589-9d0f-239b39dcd39a" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Xubuntu" PARTUUID="ec9949ad-ac5d-4d97-906b-d3963010e6f9"
/dev/sda9: LABEL="Security" UUID="62e607e2-6539-416d-b323-46ca4f5543e2" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Kali" PARTUUID="d4004d4f-0896-4184-ae85-cc2d1746b0ba"
/dev/sda10: LABEL="Hjem" UUID="7dc71844-bb39-4e9b-83c9-472f7d94b16d" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Data" PARTUUID="f4be90c7-c698-432c-8b08-175fd5c02c69"
/dev/sda11: LABEL="wmlive" UUID="009713f7-0c5a-485f-9a9b-ab59037765b9" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="WMlive" PARTUUID="52e8749e-eb56-4132-abe9-77f1aa82c528"
/dev/sda2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="e09f4516-a38d-4564-ac2e-1fdfdaef6d83"
```

The line we are looking for is:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="30AB-667B" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="623e7385-ee5d-49b8-bc18-dbde551f5067"
```

Then you have to enter that information (with your own systems UUID's) in the fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=53942c96-b474-4589-9d0f-239b39dcd39a /             ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was Missing on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=30AB-667B  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=b81dd225-11b1-4783-81ff-1572f8058c23 none          swap    sw              0       0
# Hjem was not loaded at installation /dev/sda10: LABEL="Hjem" UUID="7dc71844-bb39-4e9b-83c9-472f7d94b16d" TYPE="ext4"
UUID=7dc71844-bb39-4e9b-83c9-472f7d94b16d /mnt/hjem ext4    relatime    0   2
```

It is the line after the one that start with `# /boot/efi`

Forget the last 2 lines it is my setup- save the file (you need to edit with sudo rights - else you can't save your changes!

Now reboot and it should start propper!

Comment: @muru  Thanx a lot - that is the way it is supposed to look!
Did you have to edit each line seperately?

Comment: Hell no. I wouldn't be making these edits if that were the case. Just select the block of text and press Ctrl-K.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late in the game, but [BIOS not seeing Ubuntu installed on Acer Aspire ES1-132. Can boot via grub cli](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918083/bios-not-seeing-ubuntu-installed-on-acer-aspire-es1-132-can-boot-via-grub-cli/1078442#1078442) any use?

(worked for me on Acer Aspire ES1)

Answer (score 0):

In case you have issue when installing on UEFI BIOS (not sure if this issue is adressed only to Acer Laptops) there is a topic here that helped me solve this issue.

I will copy the commands in case it disappears, but all credit goes to Pueseso from Acer Community forum.

- Boot Ubuntu Live USB
- open terminal

```
sudo -s

ubiquity -b
```

- Press Continue testing after installation is over.
- Now we will return to the CLI (  https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall  )

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt #sda2 is the root partition
sudo mkdir /mnt/boot/efi
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi #sda1 is the efi partition
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done

modprobe efivars # make sure this is loaded
```

- notice the bootx64 file

```
efibootmgr --verbose
```

- We will reinstall grub-install for a 64bit version

```
apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64

grub-install -no-nvram --root-directory=/mnt
chroot /mnt
update-grub
cd /boot/efi/EFI
cp -R ubuntu BOOT
cd BOOT
cp grubx64.efi bootx64.efi
```

- You are finished, reboot the system.